# how to put an android view (tooltip) on top of another inner view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have two long linear layouts.

```
<LineraLayout A>
   <View 1/>
   <View 2/>
   <View 3/>
</LineraLayout A>
<LineraLayout B>
   <View 1/>
   <View 2/>
   <View 3/>
</LineraLayout B>
```

I want to include another xml of a linear layout

which will animate and point on LayoutA, view 3

but I want it to look like floating on current layout, not adding it as a child of LinearLayout A

how can I do so?

Comment: Tried using the FrameLayout?

Comment: what exactly you want can we have wire frame ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout>
    <LineraLayout A>
        <View 1/>
        <View 2/>
        <View 3/>
    </LineraLayout A>
    <ToolTipView/>
</FrameLayout>
<LineraLayout B>
   <View 1/>
   <View 2/>
   <View 3/>
</LineraLayout B>
```